# Not able to import android.widget.NumberPicker in android

Tags: android, android-widget

Hi I am using Android version 2.3.3 . I want to use NumberPicker view & I can see that in my xml code.But when I try to import NumberPicker in my java class then I didn't find it there.

Please help.

Comment: You can add compatibility library android-support-v4.jar.

Comment: But NumberPicker is not in the support Library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) was added in API Level 11. So, you can't import it to your API 10 (Android 2.3.3) project.

Alternatives:

- [android-numberpicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/): Android 4.0 NumberPicker backported to 2.1.
- [android-wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/): A flexible wheel with customized items support.

If I were you, I'll go with the first one.

Comment: The first one requires AccessibilityNodeProvider which is only in API level 16! Doesn't help at all.

Comment: Indeed, android-numberpicker library looks unfinished. You need to import android support v4 library and change almost all Accessibility* classes to Accessibility*Compat. In this case library will work with minimal API v.4

Comment: also android-numberpicker hasn't been updated for 2 years and the code doesn't render properly on Android 5.0